# How to create the elasticsearch index document from s3 json file object

Tags: json, elasticsearch, amazon-s3, logstash, pipeline

### S3 to Elasticsearch

We have JSON files in s3, ship the s3 JSON object to elasticsearch as a document(one json files in s3 to one document elasticsearch)

Push s3 JSON objects (s3 containers json files), each object will be one document)

Here is my pipeline

```
input {
    s3 {
        access_key_id => "MY_KEY"
        secret_access_key => "MY_SECRET"
        bucket => "sthreetoes"
        region => "ap-south-1"
        codec => "json"
    }
}
output {
    elasticsearch {
        hosts => "http://elasticsearch:9200"
        index => "test-data"
    }
}
```

When I run the pipeline, losgstash is shipping to index considering each key-value paid as document.

json object in s3

```json
{
    "id": 246,
    "first_name": "Lell",
    "last_name": "Bsel",
    "email": "lbros6t@sakura.jp",
    "gender": "Female",
    "ip_address": "12.12.12.8"
}
```

When we run the logstash pipeline index is created with 6 documents considering each key-value pair in JSON as a message.

Any solution to save the JSON object  as a single document